# How to host multiple site in single droplet

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I just hosted my website on the digital ocean by following below link.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

It works like a charm.

But i also want to host multiple site on the single drop let.  I've no idea that how to host multiple site on the single droplet. Does name matters while creating gunicorn service file and socket file. I mean do I need to create separate service and socket file for separate project and also do i need to create separate sock file for separate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run as much as resources (RAM, Disk space) you have. For this, there is some tips i list them below:

- Have separate virtualenvs for each site, inside its project folder.
- Manage Database names to prevent conflicts
- Don't use port 8000 and reserve it for tests.
- Create separate systemd service for each project. (remember to use separate name for each service)
- Therefore you should create separate socket for each site.
- First start with 1 worker per site, to lower your resources costs.
- Create separate nginx block for each site you have.

with these tips you can have multiple sites in an single droplet easily.

Comment: Do I need to also generate separate sock file for each project

Answer (score 1):

Yes you just have to create separate *.service and *.socket files for each project. 
And just don't forget to change all strings in this tutorial from

```
gunicorn.service
gunicorn.socket
```

to

```
your_new_project.service
your_new_project.socket
```

when I had similar question [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-deploy-multiple-django-apps-as-subdomains-using-nginx-and-gunicorn) answer from DO website helped me.

Comment: Do I need to also generate separate sock file for each project

Comment: Yes as I said, sorry for little mistake I meant separate files for each project.
Just follow along with that tutorial, and change gunicorn.sock[et] to your_new_project.sock[et] files.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the project name and server_name when doing the "Configure Nginx to Proxy Pass to Gunicorn" part. If done correctly, after you restart nginx both websites will work.

Comment: Do I need to also generate separate sock file for each project